# Associate to test case is not enabled in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, automation, visual-studio-2017

I have a unit test project and I wrote my test methods there. 
I want to Associate my automation scripts with Test cases. But when I navigate to Test Explore tab and right click it will show "Associate with Test Case" but it is disabled. 
Can any one help me with this?

Comment: Solved this. You need to search TC through Team Explore -> Work Items -> quries

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem ("Associate to test case" disabled) because of using MSTest V2 in my Project (default in VS 2017).

**To Enable "Associate to test case" just change MSTest V2 to MSTest V1 in your Project References:**

MSTest V2:
**Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework**

MSTest V1:
**Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are connected to DevOps / TFS (Under the Team Explorer, Connect)